Python: Convert Input CSV File to Standard Output CSV with slight variation in header name
Input CSV File Field Names: Any number of field name.
Output CSV File Field Names: 'DIST_ID', 'FULLNAME', 'LASTNAME', 'ADDR1'
The below python code works if both input file and output file have same headers.
But what if

I want the input file Data converted to the output file data keeping only the outFldNames from the input.
The input file Field Names are not exact.  Example Input file field name = 'DISTRIBUTION_ID'.  I need this mapped to output file: 'DIST_ID'. Some type of reference table perhaps to do the mapping?

import csv

with open('file.csv', 'r') as infile, open('reordered.csv', 'a') as outfile:
    # output dict needs a list for new column ordering
    outFldNames= ['DIST_ID', 'FULLNAME', 'LASTNAME', 'ADDR1']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, outFldNames=outFldNames= )
    # reorder the header first
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in csv.DictReader(infile):
        # writes the reordered rows to the new file
        writer.writerow(row)


Do you know in advance all variations of input field names that you want to map to out field name?

Yes.  I have all variations in the input files ahead of time

Try something like this: https://onecompiler.com/python/42fjjvrty

thank you Milos!  I think I can make that work.  God Bless
